# Dependency issues trying to install features in karaf

Tags: dependency-management, apache-karaf

I've spent the last 2 days trying to resolve dependency issues to install a feature in karaf. Karaf version: 2.3.5, here's how I set up karaf:

Create a `jpa-hibernate.xml` file, e.g. in /tmp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<features>
<feature name="jpa-hibernate" version="4.3.0-fuse-01-00">
    <bundle>mvn:org.apache.servicemix.specs/org.apache.servicemix.specs.java-persistence-api-1.1.1/1.5.0</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-dbcp/1.2.2_5</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:org.springframework/spring-jdbc/3.0.6.RELEASE</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.dom4j/1.6.1_2</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:org.antlr/com.springsource.antlr/2.7.7</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:org.objectweb.asm/com.springsource.org.objectweb.asm/1.5.3</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:net.sourceforge.cglib/com.springsource.net.sf.cglib/2.2.0</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:org.jboss.javassist/com.springsource.javassist/3.9.0.GA</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:org.hibernate/com.springsource.org.hibernate.annotations.common/3.3.0.ga</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:org.hibernate/com.springsource.org.hibernate.annotations/3.4.0.GA</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:org.hibernate/com.springsource.org.hibernate.ejb/3.4.0.GA</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:org.hibernate/com.springsource.org.hibernate/3.3.2.GA</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:org.springframework/spring-orm/3.0.6.RELEASE</bundle>
</feature>
</features>
```

And then in the client, I install a few features and bundles:

```
features:addUrl mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/2.8.3/xml/features
features:addurl mvn:org.apache.servicemix/apache-servicemix/4.4.0/xml/features
features:install cxf
features:install nmr
features:install camel
features:install camel-nmr
features:install camel-quartz
features:install camel-ftp
osgi:install -s wrap:mvn:org.apache.derby/derby/10.8.2.2
osgi:install -s wrap:mvn:mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.18
features:addurl file:///tmp/jpa-hibernate.xml
features:install jpa-hibernate
```

However, when I run this, I get an error that seems to be related to unresolveable dependencies. On the first run I got:

```
Error executing command: Could not start bundle mvn:org.springframework/spring-jdbc/3.0.6.RELEASE in feature(s) jpa-hibernate-4.3.0-fuse-01-00, spring-jdbc-3.0.6.RELEASE: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.springframework.jdbc [259]: Unable to resolve 259.0: missing requirement [259.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.beans)(version>=3.0.6)(!(version>=3.0.7)))
```

This I assumed was due to org.springframework.beans not being available. I would think that maven would resolve this. Anyway, I manually install this bundle:

```
> osgi:install mvn:org.springframework/spring-beans/3.0.6.RELEASE
> features:install jpa-hibernate
Error executing command: Could not start bundle mvn:org.springframework/spring-jdbc/3.0.6.RELEASE in feature(s) jpa-hibernate-4.3.0-fuse-01-00, spring-jdbc-3.0.6.RELEASE: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.springframework.jdbc [307]: Unable to resolve 307.0: missing requirement [307.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.beans)(version>=3.0.6)(!(version>=3.0.7))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 304.0: missing requirement [304.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.core)(version>=3.0.6)(!(version>=3.0.7)))]
> osgi:install mvn:org.springframework/spring-core/3.0.6.RELEASE
> features:install jpa-hibernate
Error executing command: Could not start bundle mvn:org.springframework/spring-jdbc/3.0.6.RELEASE in feature(s) jpa-hibernate-4.3.0-fuse-01-00, spring-jdbc-3.0.6.RELEASE: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.springframework.jdbc [321]: Unable to resolve 321.0: missing requirement [321.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.context)(version>=3.0.6)(!(version>=3.0.7)))                           
> osgi:install mvn:org.springframework/spring-context/3.0.6.RELEASE
Bundle ID: 332
> features:install jpa-hibernate
Error executing command: Could not start bundle mvn:org.springframework/spring-jdbc/3.0.6.RELEASE in feature(s) jpa-hibernate-4.3.0-fuse-01-00, spring-jdbc-3.0.6.RELEASE: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.springframework.jdbc [335]: Unable to resolve 335.0: missing requirement [335.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.dao)(version>=3.0.6)(!(version>=3.0.7)))
```

I am not able to get past this. I find it strange, because when I check the [dependencies of spring-jdbc](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/3.0.6.RELEASE) spring-dao is not listed. In addition, there is no spring-dao-3.0.6.RELEASE to manually install, that would resolve this.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you able to resolve this issue ? It would be really appreciated  if you can share how to resolve it.